# Finetune the style of two-divs with distinct colors

Tags: css

I want to set background for 2 nested divs , the outer one has red background, while the inner one has blue background, but it doesn't work. How can I use the background colors to set these two squares as two levels?

```css
#d1 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
#d2 {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"> 
  <div id="d2">
      <h1> text contents here...</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ID identifiers are not allowed to start with a number.` so you need to change in id name or you can add css like this: `[id='1']`

Comment: thanks! this answer is useful.

Comment: what is not working here?

Comment: I just modified the code according to the comment of @MinalChauhan . It's good now.